# Hadoop mapReduce Programming error exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'am getting the following error when i'am trying to execute MR Program on Hadoop.

Sample Input Date :

```
CA_25-Jan-2014  00:12:345   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   35.7    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   -22.3   13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
CA_26-Jan-2014  00:54:245   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   55.7    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
CA_27-Jan-2014  00:14:045   35.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   -22.3   03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   35.7    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
CA_28-Jan-2014  00:22:315   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   35.7    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   -23.3   12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
CA_29-Jan-2014  00:15:345   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   52.9    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   45.0    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   -2.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -17 15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
NJ_29-Jan-2014  00:15:345   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   52.9    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   45.0    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   -2.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -17 15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
CA_30-Jan-2014  00:22:445   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   56  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   35.7    06:19:345   39.6    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   -15.7   16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
CA_31-Jan-2014  00:42:245   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   49.2    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -27
NY_29-Jan-2014  00:15:345   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   52.9    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   45.0    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   -2.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -17 15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
NY_30-Jan-2014  00:22:445   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   56  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   35.7    06:19:345   39.6    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   -15.7   16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
NY_31-Jan-2014  00:42:245   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   16  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   49.2    06:19:345   23.1    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   15.7    16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -27
NJ_30-Jan-2014  00:22:445   15.7    01:19:345   23.1    02:34:542   12.3    03:12:187   56  04:00:093   -14 05:12:345   35.7    06:19:345   39.6    07:34:542   12.3    08:12:187   16  09:00:093   -7  10:12:345   15.7    11:19:345   23.1    12:34:542   12.3    13:12:187   16  14:00:093   -7  15:12:345   -15.7   16:19:345   23.1    19:34:542   12.3    20:12:187   16  22:00:093   -7
```

Desired Output:

Date Maxtemperature

I want to display the Date and the Maximum Temperature for that day.

Code:

```
``import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class MaxTemp {

public static class TempMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,FloatWritable>{

        String date;

    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String line=value.toString();
        date=line.substring(3,14);
        String items[]=line.split("\t");

        for(int i=2;i<items.length;i=i+2){
            Float temp=Float.parseFloat(items[i]);
            context.write(new Text(date),new FloatWritable(temp));
            }


    }

}

public static class TempReducer extends Reducer<Text,FloatWritable,Text,FloatWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<FloatWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Float maxvalue=Float.MIN_VALUE;

        for(FloatWritable value:values){
            maxvalue=Math.max(maxvalue,value.get());
        }

        context.write(key,new FloatWritable(maxvalue));

    }

}


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    Job job=new Job(conf,"Temp job");

    job.setJarByClass(MaxTemp.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TempMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TempReducer.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(TempReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);




}
```

}

Error:

```
16/04/23 05:25:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201605162225_0029_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:876)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at MaxTemp$TempMapper.map(MaxTemp.java:29)
    at MaxTemp$TempMapper.map(MaxTemp.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the setOutputValueClass to FloatWritable rather than Text.

`job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);`

Also add MapOutputKeyClass and MapOutputValueClass in job configuration

`job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);`